# WPF Dynamic Data Display Line plot behaviour when the data is not valid

Tags: wpf, dynamic-data-display

I'm working on a WPF application that displays range (distance) measurements in real time.
I use the chart plotter to display a line graph and refresh this at around 10Hz.
The Y-axis (distance) is fixed and the x-axis (data sample) is 'rolling'.

My question is this. When there is suddenly no target I'd like to simply break the plot until a valid range measurement is received again.

Currently when there is no target I add a value that exceeds the maximum, however this causes the graph to shoot off the scale and then when a target is within range it shoots down again. I'd like to simply have gaps in the plot to represent no target.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far the only I've seen to do this, is to end your current line graph, and when your break ends, instantiate a new linegraph and add it to your chart again with the same properties as the previous one. I'm not sure if you're using a legend, if so, that might add an extra graph to your legend, but I'm sure there's an easy programmatic way to do it. Outside of that solution, I'm not sure that there is an easy solution to that. (Apart from modifying the library yourself! If you do end up doing that, make sure you share it here, I'd be interested in seeing.)